# Quitar valor None en objeto Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

No me tira error ni nada. Solo quiero saber si hay algun metodo para evitar que en ***age*** me devuelva *None*

```
class Persona():
    def __init__(self, name, sn, age):
        self._name = name
        self._sn = sn
        self._age = age
    
    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self,name):
        self._name = name
    
    def showData(self):
        print(f"{self._name} {self._sn} - Edad: {self._age}")
```

Por ejemplo, si pongo:

```
pepe = Persona('Pepe', 'Mujica', 63)
print(pepe.showData())
```

Me retorna:

```
Pepe Mujica - Edad: 63
None
```

Que puedo hacer para que no aparezca el *None*. Ya que ahora no me molesta, pero para cuando tenga que trabajar va a ser un problema.

Gracias al que me pueda ayudar :D

Comment: en ves de `print()`, utiliza `return f"{self._name} ... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno como te dije en mi comentario, la solución es tan simple como cambiar el `print()` por un `return`.

```py
class Persona():
    ...
    def showData(self):
        return f"{self._name} {self._sn} - Edad: {self._age}"
```

Pero... por que esto?, pues el método `showData()` no deja de ser una función y al hacer el llamado a una función esta ejecuta el código que tenga dentro y devuelve un valor, si no se especifica el valor de retorno por defecto es `None`, vemos un ejemplo.

```py
def suma(a,b)
    print(a+b)

suma(1,2)
```

Si ejecutamos eso, veremos como resultado, esto

```
3
```

esto por que solo estamos ejecutando la función, la cual se encarga de hacer el `print()`, pero si hacemos un `print()` de la función, así `print(suma(1,2))`es equivalente a hacer

```
resultado = suma(1,2)
print(resultado)
```

La variable resultado contiene el valor que retorna la función, en este caso `None`, por que no se ha especificado. La manera correcta de imprimir un valor que retorna una función, es retornando dicho valor.

```py
def suma(a,b):
    return f"la suma es {a+b}" #retornamos un mensaje con la suma

print(suma(1,2))
```

Teniendo como resultado

```
la suma es 3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No sabia eso :D