# ¿Por qué este codigo me devuelve: none?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo este código y cuando hago `print()` de alguna de las variables: `el, et o B`, me devuelve: `none`. ¿Qué puede estar pasando? ¿Puede  ser solo un error de indentación o hay algo más?

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np
import random

random.seed(7)
D=2
N=32
Zc=0.25
kl=1e7
B=np.zeros((N+2,N+2))

@jit(nopython=True)
def M(B):
    B=np.zeros((N+2,N+2))
    C=np.zeros((N+2,N+2))
    s=2*D+1


    el=[]
    et=[]
    for i in range(kl):
        e=0
        for j in range(1,N+1):
            for k in range(1,N+1):
                Z=B[j,k]-((1/2*D))*(B[j+1,k]+B[j-1,k]+B[j,k+1]+B[j,k-1])
                if Z > Zc:
                    C[j,k]=  C[j,k]-((2*D)/s)*Zc
                    C[j+1,k]=  C[j+1,k]+(1/s)*Zc
                    C[j-1,k]=  C[j-1,k]+(1/s)*Zc
                    C[j,k+1]=  C[j,k+1]+(1/s)*Zc
                    C[j,k-1]=  C[j,k-1]+(1/s)*Zc
                    g=((2*D)/s)*((2*abs(Z)/Zc)-1)*(Zc**2)
                    e=e+g
                
                else:
                    continue
            
            
                if e>0:
                   for j in range(1,N+1):
                       for k in range(1,N+1):
                           B[j,k]=  B[j,k] + C[j,k]
                           C[j,k]=0
                         
               else:
                    k0=[random.randint(1,N+1),random.randint(1,N+1)]
                    deltaB=random.random()-0.2
                    B[k0[0],k0[1]]= B[k0[0],k0[1]]+deltaB
                    B[0,:]=0
                    B[:,0]=0
                    B[N+1,:]=0
                    B[:,N+1]=0
                    el.append(e)
                    et.append(np.sum(np.square(B)))
               
                
                return el ,et,B

B=M(B)
el=M(B)
et=M(B)
```

Puede que el problema esté en la indentación del `return`, si no esta ahí el problema, no sé en que otro lugar puede ser el error. Acá esta el código completo y corregido el problema de las variables que no estaban definidas.

Comment: el codigo esta bien indentado?

Comment: puedes mirar esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/461509/183782)

Comment: El código parece que está ofuscado y es muy difícil de leer rápido, además de que está mal indentado. Por favor indenta bien tu código e intenta explicar más o menos dónde crees que está el error y porqué, eso les va a ayudar mucho a los que te quieran responder y les vas a ahorrar mucho tiempo.

Comment: Hola. el problema es que me devuelve : none y nada mas , no me  devuelve el valor de la variable y ademas none. solo me dice none. nose si esta bien identado el return. puede ser ese el problema, pero no lo se. si cambio la identacion de return, me devuleve para B una matriz de ceros, como el valor que le ingreso al programa. puede estar en la identacion del return el programa, sino nose donde podria estar el error

Comment: Hay varios problemas, fuera de los ya mencionados, vi más a detalle tu código y encontré que `k`, la variable que usas en el `for` no está definida, tal vez faltan pedazos de código.
La otra es que la función `M` retorna una tupla de valores (y además recibe un parámetro que es sobreescrito) y cuando la mandas llamar, lo haces 3 veces, supongo que esperando que cada invocación retorne un valor diferente de los 3 ya mencionados, lo cual claramente no es así.
Recomiendo la lectura de [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ssj pon tu código tal y como lo tienes, además te deje un enlace, creo que es lo que buscas. No te puedo ayudar, pues tu código no esta correctamente indentado

Comment: hola. grcias por las respuestas, ahi esta bien identado el codigo y esta el codigo completo.(y se me copiaron cosas de mas arriba, si), entonces el problema es como retorna M? no puede ser otra cosa ?

Comment: cual es el resultado que esperas obtener?

Comment: @ssj lo primero que me llama la atención es que declaras kl=1e7 y después: for i in range(kl): es un decimal y range usa enteros.

Comment: Sería mucho más fácil entender tu código si usaras nombres significativos. Tal como está escrito parecen jeroglíficos y desalienta trabajar en el problema.